# Testing flash applications on web using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, microstrategy

I want to test Microstrategy applications using any web testing tools. I figured out seleniun serves my purpose well. But microstrategy applications are deployed in flash formats. Please help me to guide how to test these flash applications is there any tool available? Can I use selenium only and how to use?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Selenium cannot interact with Flash objects.

You can use FlashSelenium, which is quite old but seems to work:

http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/

Or use Sikuli, Adobe's 'Genie' library, or Ranorex's library:

http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/
http://www.ranorex.com/product/automated-ui-testing-of-flash-flex-applications.html
http://www.sikuli.org/

There is very limited tools and information for Flash UI Testing.

Another alternative is to interact with it directly using Javascript.

Comment: +1 for Adobe Genie and Sikuli.

Answer (score 2):

sikuli is a good one for it is based on JAVA so that you can add its jar file in to your build path .. Another one is AUTOIT where it is an 'easy bad' idea which is not recommend but in some case it may (or may not) come handy. As you have to give the co-ordination (x,y) of any element and enter code for it to interact with it like clicking or entering a text..