# Scrape website data for CSV

Tags: javascript, python, csv, web-scraping, scrape

Rather inexperienced with this type of programming effort, much more familiar with embedded systems. I have very little web programming xp.

What I'd like to achieve:

A website (danglefactory.com) has a great table of statistics that I'd like to download into a CSV for processing. On the website, there is a button that calls an internal script to craft a cvs and prepare for download.

Referer http://www.danglefactory.com/projections/skaters/daily

Script  http://www.danglefactory.com/scripts/copy_csv_xls.swf

I prefer a python solution, that will be able to fetch this csv either to temp or local storage for processing.

Thanks in adv.

Comment: I don't know how to catch that csv, but you could do a get on that JSON-call. And than transfer that JSON into csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First approach you can take is pretty low-level.

Under the hood, there are JSON API calls that you can simulate using, for example, [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

Here is how you can get the daily projections:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.danglefactory.com/api/DailySkaterProjections?_=1415200157912'
response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()
print data
```

Prints:

```
[{u'A': 0.61,
  u'Blocks': 0.37,
  u'Corsi': 0.53,
  u'FOL': 9.07,
  u'FOW': 8.95,
  u'FOWinPerc': 49.6,
  u'G': 0.39,
  u'Giveaways': 0.89,
  u'Hits': 0.54,
  u'Name': u'John Tavares',
  u'Opponent': u'ANA',
  u'P': 0.99,
  u'PIM': 0.51,
  u'PPA': 0.24,
  u'PPG': 0.11,
  u'PlayerID': 411,
  u'PlusMinus': 0.05,
  u'PrimaryPosition': u'C',
  u'SHA': 0.0,
  u'SHG': 0.0,
  u'ShPerc': 12.6,
  u'Shots': 3.1,
  u'TOI': 20.39,
  u'Takeaways': 0.82,
  u'Team': u'NYI'},
 {u'A': 0.7,
  u'Blocks': 1.0,
  u'Corsi': 0.47,
  u'FOL': 8.69,
  u'FOW': 8.43,
  u'FOWinPerc': 49.3,
  u'G': 0.28,
  u'Giveaways': 0.84,
  u'Hits': 1.49,
  u'Name': u'Ryan Getzlaf',
  u'Opponent': u'NYI',
  u'P': 0.97,
  u'PIM': 0.68,
  u'PPA': 0.22,
  u'PPG': 0.07,
  u'PlayerID': 161,
  u'PlusMinus': 0.06,
  u'PrimaryPosition': u'C',
  u'SHA': 0.04,
  u'SHG': 0.02,
  u'ShPerc': 11.9,
  u'Shots': 2.3,
  u'TOI': 20.52,
  u'Takeaways': 0.61,
  u'Team': u'ANA'},

  ...

}]
```

Then, you can convert the results into csv accordingly using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

---

Another solution could be to use [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) browser automation tool, but the problem is that the `CSV` button and the table is inside a Flash object which [`selenium` cannot interact with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339540/testing-flash-applications-on-web-using-selenium).

---

You can though use an image recognition and screen automation tool like [`sikuli`](http://www.sikuli.org/) to find that `CSV` button and click on it. This is if you still want to stay on the "high-level".

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you mean this one: http://www.danglefactory.com/api/DailySkaterProjections

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I knew there had to be a way to tap into the nice API they offer, and how nice it is that it's in raw JSON to start. I was originally trying to parse HTML and scrape tables and then I found your suggestion. Quickly implemented in R, even though a python solution was requested.