# How to play flash video in selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

I found  and selected. But I can't find any element like `play`.

This video is flash player powered by JW Player.

I don't know how to click to flash in selenium.

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want to do. But Try Fire Bug may b you can get elements. I have some thing like this with plural sight video player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot do it because Selenium cannot interact with flash objects.

There's **NO** html tags, **selector** etc on it.

But you can use other way to do it like using [Flash Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/)

Or you can hard code it  directly using Javascript codes.

Maybe you can refer to this one [Testing Flash Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339540/testing-flash-applications-on-web-using-selenium)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't know how to use Flash Selenium with Selenium.